# How to use an array from a query result and to then be used again for another query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The scenario is that I have a friend who will only lend me his borrowed books if he knows he can get the same books at another library. So he does the following query:

```
$collectbook= LibraryOne::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

He then needs to loop through the array to collect the relevant IDs predicting that he has 4 books however he is unsure.

```
if (isset($collectbook)) {
foreach ($collectbook as $books =>$values)

              if($books==0){
             $first_book = ($values->book_id);
            }elseif ($books==1){
            $second_book = ($values->book_id);
             }elseif($books==2) { 
            $third_book = ($values->book_id);
            }elseif($books==3) { 
            $fourth_book = ($values->book_id);
            } 
   }
```

I then runs four separate queries to check if he has the matching books

```
try {            
$collectbookone= LibraryTwo::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('item_id', $first_book)->first();
}catch(\Exception $e){

}
try {
$collectbooktwo= LibraryTwo::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('item_id', $second_book)->first();
}catch(\Exception $e){

}
try {
$collectbookthree= LibraryTwo::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('item_id', $third_book)->first();
}catch(\Exception $e){

}
try{
$collectbookfour= LibraryTwo::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->where('item_id', $fourth_book)->first();
}catch(\Exception $e){

}
```

The question is whether anyone knows a way of listing all the matching books from library one and library two in a more more elegant way than above. Not knowing how many books one has in the first place is problem..Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: haha! it's not I just worded it like this so it's easier to understand

Comment: You would make it easier on yourself if you put your try/catch that is the same, repeated 4 times, into a function..

Comment: In other words, you are trying to get a book that presents in the both libraries and belongs to a specific user?

Comment: Yes @Anatoly Arkhipov. by the way libraries are in different databases so I can't join them

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov could you please somehow point me in the right direction as to how I would turn my exceptions into functions?

Comment: @WadeShuler says about functions, not me :) I think he means something like this: http://pastebin.com/eHzp6FFQ But it is just a little refactoring for code example from your question, and you should actually just use solution from the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my mistake. I'm using the solution im just curious on how it's done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sql joins. Based on the functions you are using laravel. You have model LibraryOne and LibraryTwo. Assuming the actual table name for LibraryOne is libraryOne and LibraryTwo is libraryTwo, your code should look like this:

```
DB::table('libraryOne')->where('libraryOne.user_id', Auth::id())->join('libraryTwo', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('libraryOne.book_id', '=', 'libraryTwo.item_id')->where('libraryTwo.user_id', Auth::id());
     })
->get();
```

This would list all the books that are both on libraryOne and libraryTwo. Im just curious why the book identifier on libraryOne is book_id while on libraryTwo it is item_id. Piece of advice, learn read about sql joins. You will need that knowledge moving forward in your career.